# Preposition meaning as per sentence

Tags: prepositions

I'm unable to extract out the clear meaning of the following sentence:

*"Do you have any money **on** you?"*

I would like an elaboration on the overall meaning of the sentence in regard to use of preposition **on** before *you*.

Comment: That sentence means "Do you have any money on your person?" Or, more generally,  "Do you have any money with you?" (It's referring to having *cash* with you, not credit cards or a cheque book or access to funds electronically.)

Comment: Understood @nnnnnn

Comment: It's an interesting one - didn't realise until checking up in response to the question that it's a relatively recent usage - most uses of 'on' in the OED have refs that go right back to Old English and identify Germanic roots. The earliest recorded use for this though is 1907 (from a Joseph Conrad novel)

Comment: @nnnnnn You should write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"on you" in this sense means in your personal possession at that point, so this would typically mean in your pockets, wallet, purse etc.

> Do you have any money on you?
>
> Yea, I've got $20 in my wallet

This would be a typical use.

Money or other items not in personal possession (carried around with you) would generally not be "on you"

> Do you have you cellphone on you?
>
> No, I left it in my car